# Both Python 2 and 3 in Emacs

Tags: python, emacs, python-3.x

I have been using Emacs to write Python 2 code. Now I have both Python 2.6 and 3.0 installed on my system, and I need to write Python 3 code as well.

Here is how the different versions are set up in /usr/bin:

```
python -> python2.6*
python2 -> python2.6*
python2.6*

python3 -> python3.0*
python3.0*
```

Is there any way to set this up so that Emacs uses the correct version of Python, depending on which language I am using? For instance, C-c C-c currently runs the buffer, but it always calls python2.6, even if I am writing Python 3 code.

Comment: Are you wondering how to get Emacs to automatically detect whether you are writing Python 2 code or Python 3 code, and to call the correct Python version? Or are you asking how to change Emacs so that it calls a different command (ie. python3) in all cases when Python code is loaded into the buffer?

Comment: Obviously the first would be ideal, but that seems pretty hard, as the syntactic differences between Python 2 and Python 3 are minor. It looks like the answers to this question take care of the second case. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using python-mode.el you can try to change `py-which-shell`. In order to do this on a per-file basis you can put

```
# -*- py-which-shell: "python3"; -*-
```

at the first line of your file - or at the second line if the first line starts with `#!`.
Another choice is to put

```
# Local Variables:
# py-which-shell: "python3" 
# End:
```

at the end of your file. Perhaps you should give the full path to python3 instead of just "python3".

Comment: The file local variable doesn't work for me. It seems the py-python-command should be set with setq in dotemacs to take effect. I'll elaborate in my other answer to the original question.

Comment: I had suggested setting py-python-command but python-mode.el uses internally py-which-shell and sets py-which-shell to the value of py-python-command *before* it sees the file-local value. I have edited the answer to suggest changing directly py-which-shell.

Comment: I suspect this would be more useful for `C-h i g (emacs) Directory Variables` than for `(emacs) File Variables`

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes.  If you can distinguish Python 2 from Python 3, then it is a Simple Matter Of Programming to get emacs to do what you want.

```
(define run-python (&optional buffer)
    (with-current-buffer (or buffer (current-buffer))
        (if (is-python3-p)
              (run-python3)
            (run-python2))))

(define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") #'run-python)
```

All that's left to do is implement `is-python3-p` and `run-python3` (etc.)

Answer (score 3):

My comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501626/both-python-2-and-3-in-emacs/502422#502422).

I wrote /t/min.py which will run fine in python3 but not in python2 (dictionary comprehension works in python3)

Contents of /t/min.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- py-python-command: "/usr/bin/python3"; -*-
a = {i:i**2 for i in range(10)}
print(a)
```

Note that the shebang indicates python3 and the file local variable py-python-command too.

I also wrote /t/min-py.el which makes sure that python-mode.el (ver 5.1.0)is used instead of python.el.

Contents of /t/min-py.el

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/m/em/lisp/")
(autoload 'python-mode "python-mode" "Python Mode." t)
;; (setq py-python-command "python3")
```

Note that the last line is commented out.

I start emacs with the following command:

```
emacs -Q -l /t/min-py.el /t/min.py &
```

Now emacs is started with my alternate dotemacs /t/min-py.el and it opens /t/min.py.

When I press C-c C-c to send the buffer to python, it says the "for" part is wrong and that indicates that python2 is being used instead of python3.  When I press C-c ! to start the python interpreter, it says python 2.5 is started.

I can even change the second line of /t/min.py to this:

```
# -*- py-python-command: "chunkybacon"; -*-
```

and do this experiment again and emacs still uses python2.

If the last line of /t/min-py.el is not commented out, then C-c C-c and C-c ! both use python3.

Comment: It seems that your local variables are not evaluated. Do you see the message asking for confirmation before evaluation? otherwise what is the value of `enable-local-variables`, if it is not `t` your local variables are ignored!

Answer (score 2):

regarding jrockway's comment:

```
(defun is-python3-p () "Check whether we're running python 2 or 3."
  (setq mystr (first (split-string (buffer-string) "\n" t)))
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert mystr)
    (goto-char 0)
    (search-forward "python3" nil t)))
(defun run-python () "Call the python interpreter."
  (interactive)
  (if (is-python3-p)
      (setq py-python-command "/usr/bin/python3")
    (setq py-python-command "/usr/bin/python"))
  (py-execute-buffer))
```

This will call `python3` if "python3" is in the top line of your buffer (shebang, usually). For some reason the `(setq py-pyton-command ...)` doesn't let you change versions once you've run `py-execute-buffer` once. That shouldn't be an issue unless you change your file on the same buffer back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

With current `python-mode.el` shebang is honored.

Interactively open a Python shell just with

```
M-x pythonVERSION    
M-x python
```

will call the installed default.

http://launchpad.net/python-mode