# Emacs: Distinguish between Python 2.x and 3.x in emacs

Tags: python, emacs, versions

I use Emacs and am currently working on projects that use different versions of Python (2.x and 3.x) and both have different sets of documentation and different interactive shells.

I want to be able to distinguish between these versions in Emacs (so I read the right documentation with pylookup and also setup the correct interactive shell). How can I do this in Emacs?

Comment: Are you putting a `#!` line at the top of your files? If not, there's no way to reliably tell from the files themselves.

Comment: I don't set it :(. But if I did include #! at the start, how could I distinguish the two?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Both Python 2 and 3 in Emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501626/both-python-2-and-3-in-emacs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this older question: [Both Python 2 and 3 in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501626/both-python-2-and-3-in-emacs)