# py-python-command ignored

Tags: emacs, python-mode

I'm using python-mode 6.0.1 on OS X, emacs 23.3 (http://emacsformacosx.com/ version).

I'm trying to get `C-c C-c` to default to python 3.

I have the following in my .emacs:

```
(setq py-python-command "/usr/local/bin/python3")
```

And when I run C-h b py-python-command, it tells me the value is that (correctly).

However, running `C-c C-c` still opens 2.7.2.

I also tried adding:

```
(setq py-which-shell "/usr/local/bin/python3")
```

as suggested here: [Both Python 2 and 3 in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501626/both-python-2-and-3-in-emacs/502422#502422), but that doesn't change anything (py-which-shell does get changed, but it still launches 2.7.2).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following code to your Emacs init file:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (setq py-python-command "python3")
              (setq py-default-interpreter "python3")))
```

Answer (score 0):

py-default-interpreter  for now is an alias only, delivered for backward compatibility

You might have encountered a bug.

Please file a report giving some example code at
https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode

Should the buffer code contain a shebang specifying pythonVERSION , than this takes precedence over default setting.

You may enforce executing buffer through specific pythonVERSION by calling 
a command of class py-execute-buffer-pythonVERSION

See menu PyExec, entry Execute buffer ...